# Return a byte array from asp.net and download it from C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have an asp.net application which writes a byte array on a GET request, and i'm trying to receive that byte array in a C# application. But I only seem to receive the header when I try to download it. (totalBuff)

I'm not the best at explaining, but I hope the code will make it clearer.

ASP.NET code:

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
resp.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("D:\\Temp\\uLockStub.dll", FileMode.Open));
resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return resp;
```

C# code:

```
var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost:48976/login/login?user={0}&password={1}&hwid={2}",
                                        username, Helper.GetMd5Hash(password), uid));
var resp = httpReq.GetResponse();
var data = resp.GetResponseStream();

var buff = new byte[1024];
var totalBuff = new List<byte>();
var read = 0;

while ((read = data.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) > 0)
   {
      var tmpBuff = new byte[read];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(buff, 0, tmpBuff, 0, read);
      totalBuff.AddRange(tmpBuff);
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18034/HttpWebRequest-Response-in-a-Nutshell-Part-1

Comment: Thanks for the reply Clark, but I found an easy solution on the ASP.NET side of the issue. When replacing the "var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); -> return resp;" part with just " Response.BinaryWrite(...)" the C# side received all the data.

Comment: @user2654057 Please put your solution as an answer to your question and accept it, so anyone that stumbles here later is able to tell what the solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

Replacing

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
resp.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("D:\\Temp\\uLockStub.dll", FileMode.Open));
resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return resp;
```

with

```
Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Temp\\uLockStub.dll"));
```

solved it.

Comment: You should accept your answer (click the V on the left side ;)) http://stackoverflow.com/about